# Form validation before submit using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, mern

I have list of options and I have to valid that at least there should be 4 options.

I have paste part of that form below:

```js
$("#livechatform").validate({
  rules: {
    options[]: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 4
    }
  },
  messages: {
    options[]: {
      required: "Please enter at least 4 options",
      minlength: "Please enter at least 4 options"
    }
  },
  submitHandler: (form) => form.submit();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="custom-validation repeater" method="post" id="livechatform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/admin/poll/create">
  <div class="col-10">
    <input class="form-control" name="options[]" type="text" required>
  </div>
  
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap gap-2 mt-3">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">
      Submit <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span>
    </button>
    
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect">
      Cancel
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

But It is not working. can someone help me How to valid that ?

Comment: Do you have implemented a validation plugIn?

Comment: No. How to do it or you can also suggest another way to valid it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** you need to include the jQuery Validation Plugin

---

In your JS code are two issues: The name of the input is a string, therefor it needs to be in quotes:

```js
'options[]': {...
```

The semicolon at the end of your submitHandler is wrong - remove it. I found both issues, because i read the error messages in the console...

Furthermore you need to define indexes in the input array:

```html
<input name="options[0]" type="text">
<input name="options[1]" type="text">
<input name="options[2]" type="text">
<input name="options[3]" type="text">
```

and add the rules for each input afterwards with the selector `[name^="options"]`, which means: each element with a name, that begins with "options":

```js
$('[name^="options"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        minlength: 4,
        messages: {
          required: "Please enter at least 4 options",
          minlength: "Please enter at least 4 characters"
        }
    })
});
```

**Working example:**

i removed the unnecessary parts (like ids, classes or spans) for simplicity...

```js
$("#livechatform").validate({
  submitHandler: (form) => form.submit()
});

$('[name^="options"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        minlength: 4,
        messages: {
          required: "Please enter at least 4 options",
          minlength: "Please enter at least 4 characters"
        }
    })
});
```

```css
.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha512-rstIgDs0xPgmG6RX1Aba4KV5cWJbAMcvRCVmglpam9SoHZiUCyQVDdH2LPlxoHtrv17XWblE/V/PP+Tr04hbtA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<form method="post" id="livechatform" action="#">
  <div class="col">
    <input name="options[0]" type="text">
    <input name="options[1]" type="text">
    <input name="options[2]" type="text">
    <input name="options[3]" type="text">
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If there are no 4 option it should not be submit form, either pop up alert